# Changing of DSN in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to change the connection of the excel from JDE to SQL Server 2014. How/What should i do/change in order to connect to another DSN in my ODBC.

This is my code for cnnStr:

```
uid = Range("P_Uid")
pwd = Range("P_Pwd")
dsn = Range("P_Dsn")
cnnstr = "ODBC;DSN=" + dsn + ";UID=" + uid + ";PWD=" + pwd
```

This is the original code from VBA:

```
Dim strCnn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim z As Double
Dim w As Double
Dim Wks As DAO.Workspace
Dim Cnn As DAO.Connection
Dim Qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim Rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim date1, date2 As String
Dim x As Long
Dim w_price As Double
Dim w_amt As Double
Dim w_qty As Long
Dim Xref_Name(10) As Variant

Set Rec = Nothing
Set Wks = CreateWorkspace("WKSTmp", "", "", dbUseODBC)
Set Cnn = Wks.OpenConnection("", dbDriverNoPrompt, True, cnnstr)
Cnn.QueryTimeout = 1800
Set Rec = Cnn.OpenRecordset(SQL)
avarow = Worksheets("Ava").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Whenever i mouse over to cnnstr, i will see this code :

```
cnnstr = "ODBC;DSN=JDE;UID=abc;PWD=abc"
```

The DSN is always JDE even though i have tried to change the connection and the cnnStr above.
The details of the cnnstr is taken from a control sheet within the excel file. Changes made to the control sheet proved futile.

Please advice on how I can change the dsn so that I can get the data from SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Where is your code for `cnnStr`? It doesn't appear to be in the other code you posted. I suggest you put a breakpoint over it and see how it changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use use to connect to SQL server 2014,

Code,

```
Sub ConnectSQLServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String


    sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                               "Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.xxx,1433;" & _
                               "Initial Catalog=Staff_Manager;" & _
                               "User Id=sa;" & _
                               "Password=myPassword;"

                                Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = conn
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = conn

            strSQL = "SELECT Your SQL Statement "
            rs.Open strSQL
```

If that is what you are trying to achieve this will work.

Comment: is'nt it `UserId` in 1 word ?

Comment: @iDevlop, no it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't leave out anything important from your original code, `cnnstr` is neither a local declared variable, nor is it assigned in that routine.  Most likely you either have a `cnnstr()` function or it's a global variable being set in the `CreateWorkspace()` function.

The simplest way to find where the code is still assigning the old connection string to `cnnstr` is to use Find to search the Current Project for "cnnstr =". (Minus the quotes.)  Make sure you are searching Current Project in case the assignment is happening in a different module.